# Grouping TXT files

Tags: linux, shell, unix, cygwin

I've been trying to group a big list of txt files into sub folders, each containing random 5 files. I.e. pick 5 random files, create a new folder Group **X**, and move them to it.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What you are done for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly straightforward:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p groupX

for i in `seq 1 5`;
do
  files=($( ls *.txt ))
  RAN=`expr $RANDOM % ${#files[@]}`
  echo Moving "${files[$RAN]}" to folder groupX
  mv "${files[$RAN]}" groupX
done
```

Warning, this does no checking if there are less than 5 txt files in the directory.